# How to disable right-clicks on Plotly-Object?

Tags: javascript, r, plotly, r-plotly, jquery-ui-contextmenu

I want to use a contextmenu ([jQuery contextMenu](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html#example-code-simple-context-menu)) on top of a Plotly object.
The problem is that, when I select multiple elements with the **Box**- or **Lasso**-select tool and then right-click on a bar, it triggers a click event on that one bar and the previous selection is lost.

*How can I prevent right-clicks from happening on the Plotly-object, so just left-clicks trigger a click/select event and the right-click is reserved only for opening the contextmenu?*

[image]

Shiny-App:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

dfN <- data.frame(
  time_stamp = seq.Date(as.Date("2018-04-01"), as.Date("2018-07-30"), 1),
  val = runif(121, 100,1000),
  col = "green", stringsAsFactors = F
)

jsCode = HTML('
$(document).on("shiny:connected", function() {
    $(function() {
        $.contextMenu({
            selector: "#plot",
            callback: function(key, options) {
              switch(key){
                 case "copy":
                    console.log("Contextmenu: Copy was clicked");
                    break;
                case "paste":
                    console.log("Contextmenu: Paste was clicked");
                    break;
              }
            },
            items: {
              copy: {name: "copy", icon: "copy"},
              "paste": {name: "paste", icon: "paste"}
            }
          });
      });
});')


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.7.1/jquery.contextMenu.min.js")),
  tags$head(tags$script(src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.7.1/jquery.ui.position.js")),
  tags$head(tags$link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.7.1/jquery.contextMenu.min.css")),
  tags$head(tags$script(jsCode)),
  plotlyOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    key <- highlight_key(dfN)
    p <- ggplot() +
      geom_col(data = key, aes(x = plotly:::to_milliseconds(time_stamp), y = val, fill=I(col)))

    ggplotly(p, source = "Src") %>% 
      layout(xaxis = list(type = "date")) %>% 
      highlight(off = "plotly_doubleclick", on = "plotly_click", color = "blue",
                opacityDim = 0.5, selected = attrs_selected(opacity = 1))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution which requires to change the underlying `plotly.js` file of the plotly package.

Normal clicks are stored as `d.event.buttons = 1` and apparently right-clicks are `d.event.buttons = 2`.

So in this section;

```
graphDiv.on('plotly_click', function(d) {

});
```

I inserted an if-condition to check if `event.buttons` is 1, otherwise no click will be emitted.

This works with the current CRAN version of plotly, the dev-version is quite a bit different now.

```
  if (d.event.buttons == 1) {
    // Normal Clicks
    Shiny.setInputValue(
      ".clientValue-plotly_click-" + x.source,
      JSON.stringify(eventDataWithKey(d))
    );
    graphDiv._shiny_plotly_click = d;            
  }
```